# How Do I Point Maven To Java Source Code Dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, dependency-management

I have an Apache Archiva Repo that I've set up to handle the binary dependencies for a Maven project that I'm working on; however, the project appears to also have some dependencies on local 3rd party source code (Unsure of Distribution License). Is there a way that I can put this source somewhere that Maven can grab it from when needing to do a build? Normally source would be stored in SCM, but that doesn't seem like the right solution for java source files that I'm only using to compile (only needed at compile time), but don't want in my main "/src" directory. Elaborations and best practices appreciated, I'm pretty new to Java Development and Maven.

Comment: Do you need that source code only at compile time?

Comment: @Puce Yes, that its correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible solutions:

- Convince the 3rd party project to deploy the JAR with the class files to Maven Central (if Open Source)
- Convince the 3rd party project to deploy the JAR with the class files to your Apache Archiva Repo (if Closed Source and in the same organization)
- Convince the 3rd party project to deploy the JAR with the class files to a Maven Repository Manager of their own and register that repo in your Apache Archiva instance (if Closed Source and *not* in the same organization; not sure if Apache Archiva provides such a feature)
- Build the JAR with the class files yourself and deploy it to your Apache Archiva repo. Then declare a dependency to it as usual

Comment: So, for clarification: Dependencies always have to be packaged? (Such as into a .jar)

Comment: @BrandonSnider Yes, at least with the out-of-the-box features (jar, pom, ear, war,...). I'm not sure what is supported by custom components, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can build the Jar file of the 3rd party source code and place it under you /lib folder and provide the dependency in your pom.xml file, Now when you will build your code the dependencies will be grab from the particular jar file.

```
  <dependency>
         <groupId>--grp id name--</groupId>
         <artifactId>--artifact id--</artifactId>
         <scope>system</scope>
         <version>1.0</version>
         <systemPath>--${basedir}\lib\{name}.jar--</systemPath> (Path of jar)
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
```

*Remove "-- --" while implementing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Build Helper Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html), e.g:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>add-source</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sources>
                <source>path to where your 3rd party source code is present</source>
                ...
              </sources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```